# How would you optimize the following mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me in optimizing this mysql query in php, it takes up to 100 sec.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.X,
A.Y,
A.Z,

FROM TableAA AS A 

INNER JOIN( TableBB AS B) 

ON(A.X = B.X) OR (A.X = B.M)

WHERE B.N = '$input' OR
  A.Y = '$input' OR
  A.Z = '$input'
```

TableAA has 1 million enteries
TableBB has 9 million enteries

Is there anyother way to write this query?

edit:

TableBB has PRIMARY index on connection between N, X ,Y.
and indexes on X, N, M

TableAA has PRIMARY index on X and indexes on Y, Z

Comment: what kind of indexes do you have on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your query (formatted in a way that I can better understand it) is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.X, A.Y, A.Z
FROM TableAA A INNER JOIN
     TableBB B
     ON A.X = B.X OR A.X = B.M
WHERE B.N = '$input' OR A.Y = '$input' OR A.Z = '$input';
```

This is complex for optimization because of all the `or` clauses.  My first inclination is to write it with two joins instead of the `or`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.X, A.Y, A.Z
FROM TableAA A left outer JOIN
     TableBB B
     ON A.X = B.X and B.N = '$input' left outer join
     TableBB b2
     on A.X = B2.M and B2.N = '$input'
WHERE (B.N is not null or B2.N is not null) and (A.Y = '$input' OR A.Z = '$input')
```

This is more complicated, but you can now add indexes on `B(N, X)` and `B(N, M)` to facilitate the processing.

Handling the `or` condition on `A` is also complicated.  You can try having two indexes:  `A(Y, X, Z)` and `A(Z, X, Y)` and see if they get used.  Otherwise, you can split this into two queries:

```
(SELECT A.X, A.Y, A.Z
 FROM TableAA A left outer JOIN
      TableBB B
      ON A.X = B.X and B.N = '$input' left outer join
      TableBB b2
      on A.X = B2.M and B2.N = '$input'
 WHERE (B.N is not null or B2.N is not null) and A.Y = '$input'
)
union
(SELECT A.X, A.Y, A.Z
 FROM TableAA A left outer JOIN
      TableBB B
      ON A.X = B.X and B.N = '$input' left outer join
      TableBB b2
      on A.X = B2.M and B2.N = '$input'
 WHERE (B.N is not null or B2.N is not null) and A.Z = '$input'
)
```

This version should use the indexes mentioned above.  Of course, you need to check the `explain` plans to see if this is really the case.  But this might help with optimization.

If there is any way to simplify the conditions so they are `and` rather than `or`, then such optimization is easier.